# Non-null and non-undefined type in Flow

Tags: flowtype, non-nullable

Flow defines so called ["Maybe types"](https://flowtype.org/docs/nullable-types.html). I.e. `?string` is similar to `string | null | void` (`void` is a type of value `undefined`).

**Is there something like general type that can be of any value but `null` and `undefined`?** Basically something like `$Diff<$Diff<any, null>, void>` if `$Diff` operator was able to operate on non-object types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no some "magic" type for this, but something like this should work: `string | number | boolean | {} | []`

Answer (score 3):

It is possible using the `NonMaybeType` Flow utility type: see [$NonMaybeType](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-nonmaybe)

> `$NonMaybeType<T>` converts a type `T` to a non-maybe type. In other words, the values of `$NonMaybeType<T>` are the values of `T` except for null and undefined.

```
// @flow
type MaybeName = ?string;
type Name = $NonMaybeType<MaybeName>;

('Gabriel': MaybeName); // Ok
(null: MaybeName); // Ok
('Gabriel': Name); // Ok
(null: Name); // Error! null can't be annotated as Name because Name is not a maybe type
```

Comment: So how is type definition of `any` except for `undefined` and `null` expressed using `$NonMaybeType<T>` going to look like? I've [tried](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQ0CmAXUAPAXKAJAHKwB2AsgIYCeARigCqUAOKAPOcZQHyKagC8oYgFdo0Hv1BDiAExSQAlsRTTEiIA) `$NonMaybeType<any>` and it doesn't seem to work as expected - it allows both `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: Correct, it does not work for `any`. I did not find a workaround for it. If your function takes as an argument any types however it's possible to express the fact that it will return a non maybe type: `function test<A>(a: A): $NonMaybeType<A> { /*... */ }` (that was my use case)

Comment: "So how is type definition of any except for undefined and null expressed using $NonMaybeType<T>" - The answer is: `$NonMaybeType<mixed>`

Answer (score 0):

If you need only a "shallow" type that does not allow null or undefined:

```js
export type NotNullOrUndefined = 
   | string
   | number 
   | bigint
   | []
   | {}
```

Now, in case you want to propagate the not null and not undefined requirement in values nested under objects and arrays you will need the following:

```js
export type NotNullOrUndefined = 
   | string
   | number 
   | bigint
   | NotNullOrUndefined[]
   | { [k: string]: NotNullOrUndefined }
```